# Requests library POST request get http 450 error

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, post, web-crawler

I'm making a simple post request to an API of a website where `params` is simply a json object. It looks like the website has certain access control mechanism and it returned

```
{"status":450,"error":""}
```

and I found this

```
450 Blocked by Windows Parental Controls (Microsoft)
A Microsoft extension. This error is given when Windows Parental Controls are turned on and are blocking access to the given webpage.
```

Is there any way I can break this Windows Parental Controls restriction of the website?

Comment: Did you try stringify the json object?

Comment: @hisener what do you mean? I converted a json file into a json obj -  
with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return json.load(f)

Comment: I mean you shouldn't send json directly. You should send it as a string.

Comment: The code 450 is being returned as a part of response body. It does not have relation to HTTP status code "450".Check that by looking at response headers, the real status code is most probably 200. In the browser: development tools -> Network -> Headers -> Status code.

Comment: It is reply from application logic, not from the web server. In order to understand how to avoid that, you will need to download application source code, locate the place that generates this response with code 450 and examine it.

Comment: Are you sure it is the remote site that blocks this? Windows Parental Controls is something that runs on *your own computer* to block outgoing requests to specific urls. And if there is a block in place, then no, you would not be able to simply bypass this from 'the outside', wherever this block is located.

Comment: Last but not least, if you find this error code in a JSON response, then that number has no connection to error codes used in other contexts. You would see the Windows Parental Control response in the form of a *HTTP status*, and **not** in the body of a JSON response. You'll have to ask the API maintainers what that specific code means for that context. I *highly doubt* that 450 has the same meaning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>If you have MS parental controls on your computer, I recommend disabling it.  Otherwise, you would need to send the request from a computer or server that doesn't have MS parental controls.</del>

Since the error is server-side, my best recommendation would be to simply send the data as a string, not directly as JSON.  This could prevent MS parental controls from deciding that the request is malicious.

Comment: its not my computer but the server has access control and returned 450 response do you understand

Comment: @KingJ: how do you know that for certain? Do you the same response from other computers in different networks?

Comment: And if you found the 450 code in a response body, then chances are (close to 100% in fact) that that error code means something entirely different.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is probably right.  It might be a seperate (non-Apache) error code created by the application that you tried to access.